# Should I always close a CachedRowSet even if it goes out of scope?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, cachedrowset

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public void getUsers() {
    CachedRowSet rowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    .........     /* Initialize the rowset */
    String query = "SELECT user_id FROM users";
    rowSet.setCommand(query);
    rowSet.execute();
    .........    /* Do some job */

}
```

Here the `CachedRowSet` object is used locally in a method. Do I need to manually close it here or the contents it holds will be grabage collected automatically when the method finishes?

Comment: If there are absolutely no other references to it, it will be a candidate for garbage collection the next time garbage collection is performed; that won't necessarily happen when the method finishes, though. Does it cost you anything to close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html

> A CachedRowSet object is a disconnected rowset, which means that it
>   makes use of a connection to its data source only briefly. It connects
>   to its data source while it is reading data to populate itself with
>   rows and again while it is propagating changes back to its underlying
>   data source. The rest of the time, a CachedRowSet object is
>   disconnected, including while its data is being modified. Being
>   disconnected makes a RowSet object much leaner and therefore much
>   easier to pass to another component. For example, a disconnected
>   RowSet object can be serialized and passed over the wire to a thin
>   client such as a personal digital assistant (PDA).

that means there is no connection issue to close
so u can leave it

but i think its good practice to always close what you open and not leave it to the GC which you usually don't touch or tell when to run.

given a large enough server with many requests, if it causes open file descriptors it can eventually be an issue.
making sure resources are closed is always best